# Insert Print Statement in all method

Tags: java, netbeans

In my project there are more than 1000 methods. I need to insert the print statement in all of them.

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
```

Is there an automatic method that will insert that line in my project?

I use Netbeans IDE 7.3.

Comment: Well you could just use the regular expression functionality from NetBeans, something like _"\w+\(\)\s*{"_ and replace with _"{ System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);"_. If it's temporary ok, but otherwise rethink your design a little.

Comment: Google for "aspect oriented programming", this would allow you to do such a modification without actually touching the methods.

Answer (score 1):

As @no__seriously pointed out, the easiest way is using a **smart regular expression** or the find/replace function in your IDE.

A more sophisticated method is **aspect oriented programming (AOP)**, which allows you to define aspects (think of it as hooks or jumppoints) in your software, e.g. before calling each method. One of the most used frameworks in Java is [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/). Depending on your demands, it is a much more complex way than regular expressions but provides a lot more flexibility.